# how do i loop through an array of numbers and update the array in bash using the array values

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

I am trying to increase the values of an array of integers using a variable, but it doesn't seem to be accessing the array values properly.
It is to start from 0 in an ascending order, while incrementing the current array value at each iteration.
I tried this:

```
array=(2 0 1)
tag=(H H H)
count=0

for i in ${array[@]}
do
    if [[ "$array[$i]"="$count" ]]
    then
        array[$i]=$((${array[$i]}+1)) 
        tag[$i]="C"
    fi
count=$(($count + 1))
done
```

Instead it kept updating from 2, then 1, before 0. I want it to start from 0, since that is the index that is equal to count.
This was the output.

```
 0       H H C
         2 0 2

 1       C H C
         3 0 2

 2       C C C
         3 1 2
```

Comment: What should the array contain after the loop finishes?

Comment: start by cutting-n-pasting your code (along with appropriate shebang) into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) and make the recommended changes; also consider that `"${array[@]}"` will give you a list of the array values while `"${!array[@]}"` will give you a list of the array indices

Comment: when it finishes array=(2 1 3) tags=(changed changed changed)

Comment: update the question to show the expected results; not everyone will read through comments trying to piece together the whole picture

Comment: I don't understand the question. You're already "looping through an array of numbers and updating the array", it's just not doing what you want. What are you trying to accomplish anyway? I saw your comment with your desired output, but what does that do for you? Beware the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). Lastly, I don't understand the algorithm you're describing either. Could you break it down step by step? For more tips, like how to write a good title, see [ask].

Comment: I have updated, hope this helps

Comment: @Ifeoma your goal is to iterate over the `tag=(H H H)` array and update its elements one by one??  

Like from

`H H H` to `C H H`, then `C C H`, and eventually `C C C`. Do I get you right?

Comment: @Vab I want it to start from the array value 0, which is is the middle. So it should look like this, H C H > H C C > C C C

Comment: @Ifeoma I have modified my script once I understood your expectations, please check my answer again and see also the output is what you wanted.

Answer (score 3):

In the loop iteration you are using array *values* instead of array *indices*, which is the core of the problem. So the TL;DR is: `"${!array[@]}"`.

```bash
array=(2 0 1)
tag=(H H H)
echo "${array[@]@A}; ${tag[@]@A};"

for index in "${!array[@]}"; do
  ((++array[index]))
  tag[index]=C
  echo "${array[@]@A}; ${tag[@]@A};"
done
```

Output:

```bash
declare -a array=([0]="2" [1]="0" [2]="1"); declare -a tag=([0]="H" [1]="H" [2]="H");
declare -a array=([0]="3" [1]="0" [2]="1"); declare -a tag=([0]="C" [1]="H" [2]="H");
declare -a array=([0]="3" [1]="1" [2]="1"); declare -a tag=([0]="C" [1]="C" [2]="H");
declare -a array=([0]="3" [1]="1" [2]="2"); declare -a tag=([0]="C" [1]="C" [2]="C");
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the values you are retrieving with the `for` loop are integers that are being used as indexes to update the values of the array.  A second problem is that your conditional statement is actually an assignment, so its exit code is always 0 (true), so $count, though incrementing, affects nothing.

First time through, $i==2, the third element of `array` is incremented (array[2]==2), the third element of the `tag` array is set to *changed*

The second time through, $i==0, the first element of `array` is incremented (array[0]==3), the first element of `tag` array is set to *changed*.

The third time through, $i==1 (see comment below), the second element of `array` is incremented (array[1]==1), and the second element of the `tag` array is set to *changed*.

Promised comment: In the third iteration, other languages would have $i==2 because array[2] had been incremented in the first loop. Bash is apparently iterating over the original values of the array, despite subsequent changes.

I think what you want to do is:

```bash
declare -a array=(2 0 1)
declare -a tag=("here" "here" "here")
declare -i count=0
declare -i i

echo "$count:  ${array[*]}"
echo "   ${tag[*]}"

for (( i=0; i<${#array[*]}; ++i )); do
    (( array[i]++ ))   # no need for '$' within (( ))
    tag[$i]="changed"
    (( count++ ))
    echo "$count:  ${array[*]}"
    echo "   ${tag[*]}"
done
```

I didn't include your conditional because I can't figure out what you're trying to do with it.

I added the `echo` statements to create output similar to the output you claimed in your example.

Answer (score 0):

**FYI:** Bash indexing starts from 0 (so to change the 2-nd element you should consider index No. 1)

Note: Here the `0` in `array` is somehow equal to `3` - last element! (so, using `3` would be more user-friendly).

Assuming the `$array` values define the numbering element in `$tag` to be changed (ex. 2 for 2nd, 3 for 3rd, and so on) accordingly, the following script will do the job.

script.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#array=(2 0 1) 

# Advantage of the logic of this script is that you may have more elements
# in $tag array but are able to change only a few of them that is mentioned in $array.
array=(2 3 1) # Change 2nd, 3rd, 1st elements accordingly.
tag=(H H H)

for i in `seq 1 ${#array[@]}` ;do
  (( i-- ))
  ii="${array[i]}"
  (( ii-- ))
  tag[$ii]="C"
  echo -e "$i:\t${tag[@]}"
done
```

Output of the script.sh:

```
0:  H C H
1:  H C C
2:  C C C
```

#### Update:

Just seen your comment, will try to update my script.

> I want it to start from the array value 0, which is is the middle. So it should look like this, H C H > H C C > C C C

Script Updated, please check again!

Comment: ideally, I am trying to get the array from a file before putting in an array. How does declaring fit into that

Comment: @Ifeoma Provide your file example.

Comment: ( A 1 2 B 2 0 C 2 1 ) the letters being the name of each. I will divide into separate arrays to hold the same array name [1] being the arrival time and [2] being the process time. I'm trying to print to the screen by accessing the array values itself and not the index number.

Comment: @Ifeoma , not sure If I got you successfully. Maybe I can take a look again next week. 


Until then please accept my answer if it satisfies your question. I'd also suggest updating your question (or better asking a new one) to contain a clear file example of the file and the requirement you look for.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you need two nesting loops in this case.

- The outer loop is to scan the array once using `count`.
- The inner loop is to identify the element that have value equal to `count` (0, then 1, then 2).
- The `tag` array is to avoid increasing the same element twice.

OK, putting all that in code:

```
#!/bin/bash
array=(2 0 1)
tag=(H H H)
n=${#array[*]}                             ## array size
echo "${array[@]@A}; ${tag[@]@A};"         ## for testing
for (( count=0; count<n; ++count )); do
  for (( i=0; i<n; ++i )); do
    if [[ ${array[$i]} -eq $count && ${tag[$i]} = "H" ]]; then
      (( array[i]++ ))
      tag[$i]="C"                          ## C=changed
      break                                ## break inner loop
    fi
  done
  echo "${array[@]@A}; ${tag[@]@A};"       ## for testing
done
```

Results:

```
declare -a array=([0]="2" [1]="0" [2]="1"); declare -a tag=([0]="H" [1]="H" [2]="H");
declare -a array=([0]="2" [1]="1" [2]="1"); declare -a tag=([0]="H" [1]="C" [2]="H");
declare -a array=([0]="2" [1]="1" [2]="2"); declare -a tag=([0]="H" [1]="C" [2]="C");
declare -a array=([0]="3" [1]="1" [2]="2"); declare -a tag=([0]="C" [1]="C" [2]="C");
```

(sorry for my broken English)

Comment: I had to change the if statement to if [[ $array[$i]}=$count && $tag[$i]="H" ]]; then because I got "invalid assignment operator". But that only increments the item in the [0] element in array and tag